# Can I close from the return of utf8::is_utf8 that a decoding layer for STDIN is set or not?

Tags: perl, stdin, decoding

Is it right to say: if a string read from `STDIN` checked with `utf8::is_utf8` returns true then there is set a decoding layer for `STDIN`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );

my $in = <STDIN>;
say utf8::is_utf8( $in ) ? 'YES' : 'NO';    # YES

binmode STDIN, ':bytes';
$in = <STDIN>;
say utf8::is_utf8( $in ) ? 'YES' : 'NO';    # No

binmode STDIN, ':encoding(latin1)';
$in = <STDIN>;
say utf8::is_utf8( $in ) ? 'YES' : 'NO';    # YES
```

Comment: I'd be cautious jumping to conclusions like that. All `utf8::is_utf8` really tells you whether Perl considers it to be utf8 encoded internally, which it also happens to do with latin1 encoding and input as per the last lines of your example. It doesn't know how it got the string or what's been done to it elsewhere. What is it you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to know if `binmode STDIN ':encoding(...)` is set. If is set I would let return a subroutine decoded strings else not decoded strings.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about `<>`, or about scalars in general? (Gotta go, but will be back later.)

Comment: It is for the `readline` method in https://metacpan.org/source/KUERBIS/Term-ReadLine-Tiny-0.002/lib/Term/ReadLine/Tiny.pm. Until now the encoding/decoding in the method worked for me but I don't know if I have tested it well enough.

Comment: @sid_com: If your situation is complex then you may want to use the facilities of the [`Encode`](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode) module directly instead of getting `readline` to do it implicitly

Comment: Term::Readline::Tiny::readline doesn't read from a file handle, at least not directly. It reads using a plugin, and goes knows what the plugin does. As such, `utf8::is_utf8` does not indicate anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is_utf8` function (whether it is from `utf8` or from `Encode`) just tells you whether a string has the internal `UTF8` flag set. That is pretty much a consequence of what you have *said* it contains yourself, and is very different from it being *valid* UTF-8.

If you want to check the capabilities of a file handle then you should take a look at the [`PerlIO::Layers`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO::Layers) module. A call like

```
query_handle(*STDIN, 'utf8')
```

will return *true* if the handle is UTF-8-capable, by setting either `:utf8` or `:encoding(utf8)`.

If you want to check specifically for `:encoding(utf8)` then you need

```
query_handle(*STDIN, 'layer', 'encoding')
```

but note that this will show only whether there is an `:encoding()` layer of any sort, which could be `:encoding(iso-8859-1)`.

If you really need to check *which* encoding is in place, the only way I know is to examine the return value of `get_layers` from the same module. It returns a list of arrays corresponding to the PerlIO layers in effect on the handle. Something like this

```
(
  ["unix",     undef,  ["CANREAD", "OPEN"]],
  ["encoding", "utf8", ["FASTGETS", "CANREAD", "LINEBUF", "UTF8"]],
)
```